# Swap memory issue in openshift jenkins making it slow

Tags: jenkins, openshift, devops

I am running builds on openshift jenkins and due to swap memory issue jenkins is running very slow and as result builds are taking longer time or failing. Is there a possible way to increase the efficiency of jenkins or improving the speed of jenkins??

Comment: Increase its available memory?

Comment: how can i achieve that?

Comment: jenkins is inside an openshift pod??

Comment: https://docs.openshift.com/aro/3/using_images/other_images/jenkins_slaves.html

Comment: Do we have a method to clear the swap memory? which is showing 0 B.